# expand plot for readability without expanding lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting 2 lines and a dot, X axis is a date range. The dot is most important, but it appears on the boundary of the plot. I want to "expand" the plot further right so that the dot position is more visible.
In other words I want to expand the X axis without adding new values to Y values of lines. However if I just add a few dates to X values of lines I get the "x and y dimensions must be equal" error. I tried to add a few np.NaN values to Y so that dimensions are equal, but then I get an error "integer required".
My plot:
[image]
My code:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
plot_x = train_original.index.values
train_y = train_original.values
ax1.plot(plot_x, train_y, 'grey')
x = np.concatenate([np.array([train_original.index.values[-1]]), test_original.index.values])
y = np.concatenate([np.array([train_original.dropna().values[-1]]), test_original.dropna().values])
ax1.plot(x, y, color='grey')
ax1.plot(list(predicted.index.values), list(predicted.values), 'ro')
ax1.axvline(x=train_end, alpha=0.7, linestyle='--',color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the [xlim()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim). Something like:

```
xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()   # return the current xlim
plt.xlim(xmax=xmax+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

An easy, automatic way to do this, without needing knowledge of the existing `xlim` is to use [`ax.margins`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins). This will add a certain fraction of the data limits to either side of the plot. For example:

```
ax.margins(x=0.1)
```

will add 10% of the current x range to both ends of the plot.

Another method is to explicitly set the x limits using [`ax.set_xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim).